# Only keep rows by group for which first is a certain value SAS

Tags: sas

I have sorted data as

```
ID value1 value2 
1    A       1
1    A       2
1    A       1
2    A       2
2    B       1
3    A       1
3    B       1
3    B       1
```

I want to change this data to a new data set where I have only the data of ID's whose last value1 was B. I.e. it should look like this:

```
ID value1 value2 
2    A       2
2    B       1
3    A       1
3    B       1
3    B       1
```

I have tried

```
data want;
set have; 
by ID;
if last.value1 = 'B' then output;
run;
```

But that didn't work. Could someone help me out? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A technique known as DOW + sequential looping allows you to:

- Loop over a group in order to compute some state variables(s).  In this case the variable is for tracking the state *is the value1 in the last row of the group = 'B'* ?
- Utilize the state variable, while looping over the same group, according to your criteria.  In this case *output the row if the group is wanted*. This loop relies on the DO loop feature that limits are determined once at loop initialization.

The original data must be sorted by the group variables.

```
data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
  end;
  %* _n_ is group size at this point;

  _want_group = value1 = 'B';  %* state variable -- is B in last row?;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;   %* process the group again, using a different SET buffer;
    set have;          %* same data set as in the do/until;
                       %* no by required because loop limit _n_ is group size;
    if _want_group then
      OUTPUT;          %* output all rows of group as desired;
  end;

  drop _want_group;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be in multiple steps. The first step would be to create a dataset with all ID's that have 'B' as the last value.

```
data tmp;
set have;
by ID value1;
if last.ID and value1='B' then output;
run;
```

Now the dataset `tmp` has all of the ID's that you want so you can select those ID's from the original dataset.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select *
from have
where id in (select distinct id from tmp);
quit;
```

If you want to do this problem in one data step, then you can sort the original table by value1 descending and run through the following data step.

```
proc sort data=have;
by id descending value1;
run;

data want(where=(keep_flag));
set have;
by id descending value1;
retain keep_flag;
if first.id and value1='B' then keep_flag=1;
else if first.id then keep_flag=0;
run;
```